# calculate if date value occurs between two different times python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time, between

I am trying to create a new column to determine if a row value is "between business hours". To do this I am trying to use the between time function. *I dont need to use it if there is an easier way.*

I have a dataframe with columns for **'Date'**, **'StartHour'**, **'End Hour'**.

**Question:**

I would like to give a 'True' or 'False' if the time in the '**Date**' column is between the '**StartHour**' and '**EndHour**' time.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#create dataframe with dates
d = {'Date': ['2016-11-17 05:01:45','2011-01-04 16:34:00','2011-01-05 09:25:45',
              '2011-01-10 12:00:45','2011-01-14 07:05:45','2011-01-15 10:19:00',
              '2011-01-17 13:59:45','2011-01-19 18:39:45','2011-01-22 06:19:45'], 
     'StartHour': ['16:00','16:00','16:00','16:00','16:00','16:00','16:00','16:00','16:00'],
     'EndHour': ['10:00','10:00','10:00','10:00','10:00','10:00','10:00','10:00','10:00'],
     'Station_ID': ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
#convert date column to datetime
df['Date'] = df['Date'].values.astype('datetime64[ns]')


#************************
# set index to Date (need for 'between_time')
df = df.set_index('Date')

# run calculation for between time
df['between_business_hours'] = df.index.isin(df.between_time('16:00', '10:00', include_start=True, include_end=True).index)


df
```

I have calculated a column using the between_time function but this only lets me use hard coded values for the start and end time. I would like to use the values in the 'StartTime' and 'EndTime' columns. I am probably making this more difficult than it needs to be by using the between_time function.

I would like the output to looks something like this.

```
                    EndHour StartHour   Station_ID  between_business_hours
Date                
2016-11-17 05:01:45  10:00   16:00       A            True
2011-01-04 16:34:00  10:00   16:00       A            True
2011-01-05 09:25:45  10:00   16:00       A            True
2011-01-10 12:00:45  10:00   16:00       A            False
2011-01-14 07:05:45  10:00   16:00       B            True
2011-01-15 10:19:00  10:00   16:00       B            False
2011-01-17 13:59:45  10:00   16:00       B            False
2011-01-19 18:39:45  10:00   16:00       B            True
2011-01-22 06:19:45  10:00   16:00       B            True
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need set the `index`

```
df.Date.dt.strftime('%H:%M').between(df.StartHour,df.EndHour)
Out[297]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8    False
dtype: bool
```

Update

```
l=[df.loc[[y],:].index.indexer_between_time(df.loc[y,'StartHour'],df.loc[y,'EndHour'])==0 for y in df.index]
df['New']=l
df.New=df.New.str[0].fillna(False)
df
                    EndHour StartHour Station_ID    New
Date                                                   
2016-11-17 05:01:45   10:00     16:00          A   True
2011-01-04 16:34:00   10:00     16:00          A   True
2011-01-05 09:25:45   10:00     16:00          A   True
2011-01-10 12:00:45   10:00     16:00          A  False
2011-01-14 07:05:45   10:00     16:00          B   True
2011-01-15 10:19:00   10:00     16:00          B  False
2011-01-17 13:59:45   10:00     16:00          B  False
2011-01-19 18:39:45   10:00     16:00          B   True
2011-01-22 06:19:45   10:00     16:00          B   True
```

Comment: THANKS! this is much more elegant than what I had going on. It works perfectly for what I was trying to do.

Comment: I thought that your answer worked. But after looking deeper I see a big issue. Your code works only if the start and end times are during the same day. IE, start at 10am and end at 4pm. The problem I am having is that the "Start time" occurs at the end of the day, lets say 16:00 Hours and the "End TIme" occurs the next day at lets say "10:00 am". As you can see from the new example, my current code works, but yours gave false readings

Comment: @brandog do you want me to fix it >

Comment: It does not seem to fix the problem? everything still comes out as false?

Comment: @brandog I think if that think happen you should go with `between_time`

Comment: Ok, The problem I have with between_time is that I want to put in the row value from the time column in the "start" and "end" time of the between_time function. I just dont understand how I could do that. Does that make sense? ie, for each row, start_time="some column number", end_time="some column number, then calculate the between time.

Comment: There we go! thanks that does it. I checked a bunch of different variations in the column values and they all worked. Its going to take me some time to dissect how you actually came up with that one line equation though haha. thanks!