# How to use between_time on one dataframe, referencing a second dataframe for time variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a set of instructions that include a start time and an end time. I have a second dateframe with another set of instructions with just a timefrom.

The instructions from the second dataframe are only included, if the timefrom does not fall between the times in the first df. Essentially the 1st dataframe times take precedent.

I would like to reference the dataframes and drop the times in the second dataframe that are superseeded by the first.

This code loops over numerous dataframes associated to different machines.

I have been using a combination of df.iat and df.between_time but with no luck.

I also tried .loc as per the following link but it doesn't seem to work when referencing the start and end times from a separate dataframe.
[calculate if date value occurs between two different times python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54204601/calculate-if-date-value-occurs-between-two-different-times-python-pandas)

```
df=  
           timeFrom             timeTo
 1. 2013-10-09 05:28:00   2013-10-10 05:31:00
 2. 2013-10-09 05:53:00   2013-10-10 06:01:00
 3. 2013-10-09 05:56:00   2013-10-10 06:03:00

df2 =      timeFrom       x
 1. 2013-10-09 05:30:00   2100
 2. 2013-10-09 05:43:00   5
 3. 2013-10-09 05:55:00   50



df2 = df2.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df2["timeFrom"]))

 for i in range(1, len(df)):
   start = df.iat[i, 2]
   end = df.iat[i, 3]
   df2 = df2.drop(df2.between_time(start, end).index)
```

I would like df2 returned with the only instruction that need to be processed. In this case:

```
2. 2013-10-09 05:43:00   5
```

However the current code results in:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert arg ['2019-05-01 05:28:00'] to a time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the above code works, however the df.between_time function only accepts arguements in time format. Therefor the dates need to be converted to an Hour:Minute format as follows:

```
start_time = dt.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime("%H:%M")
```

Full code below:

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    start = df.iat[i, 1]
    end = df.iat[i, 2]
    if start > BeginTime and end < EndTime:
            start_time = dt.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime("%H:%M")
            end_time = dt.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime("%H:%M")
            df2 = df2.drop(df2.between_time(start_time, end_time).index)
```